# Can't connect with Woocommerce using WooCommerceNET C# because of version

Tags: c#, api, woocommerce

I am trying to connect with WooCommerce using API v2. 
I am using  WooCommerceNET=0.8.1 and NETFramework=v4.7.2

Code:

```
using WooCommerceNET;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v2;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v2.Extension;

...
public void AddToWoocomerce()
        {
            string consumerKey = "ck_....";
            string consumerSecret = "cs_...";

            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://makm862.vot.pl/wp-json/wp/v2/", consumerKey, consumerSecret);

            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);  
        }
```

I got exception:

```
Please use WooCommerce Restful API Version 2 url for this WCObject. e.g.: http://www.yourstore.co.nz/wp-json/wc/v2/
```

- It worked fine with Python (https://pypi.org/project/WooCommerce/) before, but I need in C#.
- Legacy API enabled
- Read/Write mode
- WooCommerceNET.0.8.0 also checked

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is

> wp/v2/

It should be:

> wc/v2/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that't right. I copied it from example with

```
WPObject wc = new WPObject(rest);
```

not

```
WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
```

and didnt noticed there is other url.

Sorry for such a trivial problem.